# How to assign the User Id to Foreign Key

Tags: go, beego

```
type Users struct {
    Id       int `orm:"pk;auto"`
    Username string
    Password string
    Salt     string
    Email    string `orm:"unique"`
}

type Post struct {
    Id          int    `orm:"pk;auto"`
    Users       *Users `orm:"rel(fk)"`
    Author      string
    Title       string    `form:"title,text,Title:" valid:"MinSize(5); MaxSize(20)"`
    Description string    `form:textarea`
    Date        time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
}
```

I am trying to assign value to `Users` as it is the foreign key. I want to assign the user id who is logged in. How to assign the user id from `Users` struct to user id in `Post` struct which is foreign key.

```
o := orm.NewOrm()
o.Using("default")
post := models.Post{}
users := models.Users{}

if this.Ctx.Input.Method() == "POST" {
    inputs := this.Input()

    post.Author = sess.(string)
    post.Title = inputs.Get("title")
    post.Description = inputs.Get("description")
    post.Date = time.Now()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, answering your question:

```
post.Date = time.Now()
// This is your last line
// Up until now all good
post.Users = &users // Actually the naming is bad, should be post.User = user
o.Insert(users) // First create user 
o.Insert(post) // Then insert post
```

This is very similar to the basic example BeeGo ORM provides: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md

In real world, you'll notice that most of the time you have a user, and you only want to create it once. So you'll switch first `Insert` to `ReadOrCreate`: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/object.md#readorcreate

Having said that, from my experience, using MVC and ORM frameworks with Go is a bad idea.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't allow me to assign users to Post.Users. It says model.users cannot be used as assignment to *model.Users.

Comment: And the thing i m trying to store in posts.Users is the id of currently logged in user

Comment: Didn't notice how you init Users, should be `post.Users = &users` then. Updated my answer.